# How to use a combination of alphabets as access-key?

Tags: asp.net, access-keys

I want to use a combination of alphabets as access key but how to use i could not make out please help this regard?

also i want to know the shortcut key for auto-hide symbol for any window(Properties, SolutionExplorer etc)